# Load external div into site with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading some external div (class = police) to my site (into div with class = "pokaz") with JQuery.

```
$('figure').on('click', function() { 
$('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
$(".pokaz").load("work1.html .police");

});
```

It works fine. But problems starts when I need to reload earlier div by clicking button situated on div with class = "police".

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function()  { 
$('.police').fadeOut(1000);
$(".pokaz").load('.loader');
});
```

It doesn't reload at all. I'm trying to do that without using iframe.
Here's fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rfz2fLLq/2/

I hope it's understandable. Help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your browser console, it says that **"$ is not defined"** which simply means that you have not added Jquery file to you page.
We need to add Jquery so $ is initialized.

Comment: Hm, also thought about that, but its not possible - I got JQuery added to both files - main and work1.html too. Maybe I've configured wrong fiddle files (did it several times only) but as  I wrote I got Jquery added in  my real project.

Comment: Abhilab-Systematix probably means your fiddle. It doesn't load jQuery and the other resources you are trying to get with jQuery.load() are also not available. You have to fix this first.

Comment: Ok I added Jquery, it shows many errors now but seems to work (button fades out when clicked). Dont  know if it resolves Your claims because I cant attach external file - work1.html into fiddle. But here's edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rfz2fLLq/7/

Comment: $('figure').on('click', function() { 
$('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
var police = $(".police").html();
console.log(police);
$(".pokaz").html(police);
});

Comment: Try replacing this function, is this your requirement ?

Comment: Unfotunately  Abhilab-Systematix, it doesn't work either. Thanks for Your advices anyway. I'm going to use window refresh instead of load(). It works despite site must be loaded again.